# Automatic conversion from html helpers to asp tag helpers in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I will try to keep this one brief.

Is there any way to automatically convert all html helpers like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show index", "Index", new {itemId = Model.Id })
```

to asp tag helpers:

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Show index</a>
```

It should not be impossible, but I just cant find any plugin or extension that does this.
Note: I am using latest VS community with ReSharper and .NET Core 3.1

Comment: What is your process? When do you want to switch? Do you need a conversion tool or do you want to create a conversion tool?

Comment: @YongqingYu Ideally, I want a button that I click and all html helpers in file instantly turn into asp tag helpers. I do not need the other way around but it would not hurt. I need it because the scaffolded files use html helpers and asp tags are much more powerful and easier to use. I would like an existing tool, I am not looking to make one.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. I was going to write a plugin but its prob easier just to do it manually